# Plain TeX \loop \repeat tracing output is incorrect

Tags: plain-tex

```
\tracingall=1
\newcount\n \n=20
\loop\the\n \advance\n by-1 \ifnum\n>0 \repeat
\bye
```

will get out like:

```
*\loop #1\repeat ->\def \body {#1}\iterate 
#1<-\the \n \advance \n by-1 \ifnum \n >0 
{\def}

\iterate ->\body \let \next \iterate \else \let \next \relax \fi \next 

\body ->\the \n \advance \n by-1 \ifnum \n >0 
{\the}
{the character 2}  % here should be 20
{\advance}
{\ifnum}
{true}
{\let}
{\else}

\next ->\body \let \next \iterate \else \let \next \relax \fi \next 

\body ->\the \n \advance \n by-1 \ifnum \n >0 
{\the}
{the character 1}  % here lost number 9, actually should be 19
```

In summarise, if `\n` is greater than 10, tracing output log will only get the 1st number and lost the latter.

Comment: `\tracingall` doesn't take a value; it's a declaration that sets several values. In order to turn it off, use `\tracingnone`.

Answer (score 6):

TeX doesn't show all characters that start a “word”, only the first one.  If you write:

```
\tracingcommands=1
\tracingonline=1
hello world!
```

TeX will show

```
{the letter h}
{horizontal mode: the letter h}
{blank space  }
{the letter w}
{blank space  }
```

so in the same way in your loop or with just:

```tex
\tracingcommands=1
\tracingonline=1
20 19 18
```

it shows only the first characters:

```
{the character 2}
{horizontal mode: the character 2}
{blank space  }
{the character 1}
{blank space  }
{the character 1}
{blank space  }
```

---

Also, `\tracingall` is a macro without arguments, so you don't write `\tracingall=1` but just `\tracingall`.

---

If you use LuaTeX, however, it shows everything:

```
{the character 2}
{horizontal mode: the character 2}
{the character 0}
{blank space  }
{the character 1}
{the character 9}
{blank space  }
{the character 1}
{the character 8}
{blank space  }
```